# DownloadManager Import Error

Tags: android, download-manager

I'm trying to implement a code with DownloadManager but I have an import error:

> ```
>  The import android.app.DownloadManager cannot be resolved
> ```

Do i have to add anything to the project in order to use this library??

Thank you very much,

Lucía

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) exists only since API level 9 (2.3/Gingerbread), do you use 9 or higher ?

Comment: OOk!I'm using 7!!Thank you very much!I'm going to try with 9!

Comment: Be carefull, if you restrain your application to Api level 9, only 2.3/Gingerbread (and higher) user will be able to use it.

Comment: But...the import should not work anyway? even if it doesn't works in the emulator afterwards?

Comment: It's depend of your build target, in eclipse you can go to project proprieties > android. And no if you use an api level under 9, eclipse  won't let you import inexistent class :)

Comment: Ok!Do you think I should look other way of downloading files that don't restrain the Api? Or API 9 is not too high?

Comment: You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to download your file, but have not DownloadManager specificities, like restore on reboot, display in notification bar...